# Implementation of scipy.signla.filtfilt in c++?

Tags: c++, signals, signal-processing

I am trying to implement scipy.signal.filtfilt function in c++ and I am wondering if there is already an implementation available of this?

Answer (score 3):

I know its a long time. but maybe you find this repository useful:
[FiltFilt](https://github.com/KBaur/FiltFilt) in C++

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31674880)

Answer (score 0):

filtfilt applies an IIR filter twice, once going forward, once going backward. The nontrivial part is how to initialize the IIR filter at the boundaries.

As a starting point, look at how [scipy.signal.filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) does it. Here is the code:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L3870

You might also find it useful to look at the source code for Octave's filtfilt (M code):
https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/signal/ci/default/tree/inst/filtfilt.m

To reproduce filtfilt in C++, you need a C++ implementation of IIR filtering to take the role of scipy's lfilter plus some boundary handling logic. I don't know about an existing C++ implementation of filtfilt, but at least for the default `method='pad'` logic, the core computation seems simple enough to consider porting directly.

Answer (score 0):

Scipy's filtfilt is similar to [Matlab's filtfilt](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html).

A question for [MATLAB's filtfilt](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html) [was previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675053/matlabs-filtfilt-algorithm)

An implementation for the same [was previously shared on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27270420) by @darien-pardinas

Do note I say [similar because as mentioned by](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/47945) @paco-wong

> The difference is in the default padding length. In matlab's filtfilt, it is 3*(max(len(a), len(b)) - 1), and in scipy's filtfilt, it is 3*max(len(a), len(b)).

So you will have to account for that